# Force javascript to open new page in tab not window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

My biggest issue is I dont the words of what I want to do so its hard to search for it.

Currently I have an iframe on a page that uses javascript to post a form to a site and then display the results in the iframe. It mimics a user login so the content in the iframe shows the user logged in and does not have to do anything. I am looking for a way to get the same behavior but after the iframe is open i want a button on the page that if pressed forces the content to a new tab instead of an iframe. I am able to alter the form info before the javascript submits it to have a target of _blank but this forces it to open in a new window not a new tab. I understand this could be expected behavior but my browser settings are set to force this into a new tab so something in the submit is overriding my settings.

Is there a way to use javascript to submit a form to a site and have the results displayed in a newtab?

Comment: you cannot do anything in html/javascript to force a tab instead of a window. that's purely browser-controlled behavior.

Answer (score 1):

No. How/where tabs are opened is browser, OS and user-settings dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Just allow the standard behavior to happen however the browser requires the form to be posted, but then override that with an ajax post and response, and suppress the default form submit.  I think you're looking for "new information to display", and that can be displayed *in the current page* instead of dealing with new tabs at all.